# Justifiying moving the limit inside the integral $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I want to justify moving the limit inside of this integral:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}$$

My idea is to use DCT. The function inside is dominated by $e^{-x}$. By taking absolute values we get the inside is always smaller (on $[0,\infty)$) than $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}\leq e^{-x}$$
Where the inequality comes from the power series of $e^x$. Thus we can apply DCT.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It looks good to me.
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}dx
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}1_{(0,n)}(x) dx$